# Code countdown timer to countdown till 930 livestream, have 30 min of saying LIVE NOW, and then countdown till 1100?

Tags: timer, countdown

I would appreciate any help possible with this as I'm learning and don't have a ton of coding knowledge. I've got a countdown timer that counts down to a 1100 live-stream on Sunday, but I want it to countdown to a 0930 live-stream first, then maybe have 30 minutes where it just says "Live now" and then starts to countdown to the 1100 service after that. How would I accomplish this?

Here is the coding I currently have:

```
var secTime;
var ticker;

var mode = "weekday"; // or "sunday" depending on a function yet to be written

function getSeconds() {
  var nowDate = new Date();
  var dy = 0; //Sunday through Saturday, 0 to 6
  if (mode == "weekday") {
    var countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 09, 30, 00);
  }
  if (mode == "weekday") {
    var countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 11, 00, 00);
  }

  var curtime = nowDate.getTime(); //current time
  var atime = countertime.getTime(); //countdown time
  var diff = parseInt((atime - curtime) / 1000);
  if (diff > 0) {
    curday = dy - nowDate.getDay()
  } else {
    curday = dy - nowDate.getDay() - 1
  } //after countdown time
  if (curday < 0) {
    curday += 7;
  } //already after countdown time, switch to next week
  if (diff <= 0) {
    diff += (86400 * 7)
  }
  startTimer(diff);
}

function startTimer(secs) {
  secTime = parseInt(secs);
  ticker = setInterval(tick, 1000);
  tick(); //initial count display
}

function tick() {
  var secs = secTime;
  if (secs > 0) {
    secTime--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(ticker);
    if (mode == "sunday") {
      mode = "weekday"
    } else {
      mode = "sunday"
    }
    getSeconds(); //start over
  }

  var days = Math.floor(secs / 86400);
  secs %= 86400;
  var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
  secs %= 3600;
  var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  secs %= 60;

  //update the time display
  document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = curday;
  document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours;
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = ((mins < 10) ? "0" : "") + mins;
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = ((secs < 10) ? "0" : "") + secs;
}
```

```
<body onload="getSeconds();">


<h6><a href="http://www.applewood.church/media/live-stream/"><font color="#ffffff"> Live in <span class="days" id="days"></span><span class="smalltext"> days,</span>
    <span class="hours" id="hours"></span><span class="smalltext"> :</span>
    <span class="minutes" id="minutes"></span><span class="smalltext"> :</span>
    <span class="seconds" id="seconds"></span><span class="smalltext"></span>
 </a></font></h6>

</body>
```

I feel like this shouldn't be super hard, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

I've tried adjusting the  `var countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 09, 30, 00);` with the time and it doesn't provide that switch